# VC2019 address sanitizer no symbolic stack trace 64bit

Tags: c, visual-studio, address-sanitizer, cl

The following simple program

```
#include <malloc.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char* arr=malloc(10);
    arr[10]='\0';
    return 0;
}
```

builds fine with VC2019 16.8.2 in 32 and 64 bit dynamic linking, however I get only in 32bit a stack trace with symbols.

32 bit: the stack is printed with function names (main)

```
@echo off
rem small sample how to build a sample c prog with asan 32bit and the good stack trace
del /q *.pdb *.obj *.exe
cl -c -Zi -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -DEBUG -MD -fsanitize=address -Fo:xx.obj xx.c
link /incremental:no /DEBUG:FULL /OUT:xx.exe /wholearchive:clang_rt.asan_dynamic-i386.lib /wholearchive:clang_rt.asan_dynamic_runtime_thunk-i386.lib xx.obj
xx.exe

>build_xx_32.bat
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

xx.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

=================================================================
==5284==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x02c0075a at pc 0x00361060 bp 0x010ff7fc sp 0x010ff7f0
WRITE of size 1 at 0x02c0075a thread T0
    #0 0x36105f in main C:\Users\leo\w\gdc\misc\testprograms\asan\xx.c:5
    #1 0x3616c9 in _scrt_common_main_seh d:\agent\_work\57\s\src\vctools\crt\vcstartup\src\startup\exe_common.inl:288
    #2 0x760ffa28  (C:\windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x6b81fa28)
    #3 0x77cc75f3  (C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x4b2e75f3)
    #4 0x77cc75c3  (C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x4b2e75c3)
```

64 bit: the stack is only printed using hex address values.

```
@echo off
rem 64bit: no symbolication of the call stack
del /q *.pdb *.obj *.exe
cl -c -Zi  -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -DEBUG -MD -fsanitize=address -Fo:xx.obj xx.c
link /incremental:no /DEBUG:FULL /OUT:xx.exe /wholearchive:clang_rt.asan_dynamic-x86_64.lib /wholearchive:clang_rt.asan_dynamic_runtime_thunk-x86_64.lib xx.obj
xx.exe

> build_xx_64.bat
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.28.29336 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

xx.c
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.28.29336.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

=================================================================
==9804==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x11d16408003a at pc 0x7ff6038d107d bp 0x000892dafd30 sp 0x000892dafd38
WRITE of size 1 at 0x11d16408003a thread T0
    #0 0x7ff6038d107c  (C:\Users\leo\w\gdc\misc\testprograms\asan\xx.exe+0x14000107c)
    #1 0x7ff6038d17df  (C:\Users\leo\w\gdc\misc\testprograms\asan\xx.exe+0x1400017df)
    #2 0x7ffd5d137033  (C:\windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL+0x180017033)
    #3 0x7ffd5ddbd0d0  (C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll+0x18004d0d0)
```

any clue why 64 bit is different ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't call `vcvars64.bat` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat`)

I did set all library paths manually and also did set the `PATH` to the `llvm-symbolizer.exe` ( located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX64\x64` ) but apparently the `clang_rt.asan_dynamic`... libs seem to look at another environment variable to perform the symbolizing.

It turned out after trial and error that for 64bit the symbolizing looks *additionally* in the `PATH` and searches `msdia140.dll` (found in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64` in my VC installation ).

The summary is that the `PATH` need to point to the directories containing `llvm-symbolizer.exe` and `msdia140.dll` in order to let the symbolizer work correctly.

2nd solution: I discovered that there is also the ability to override the location of `llvm-symbolizer.exe` with the env variable `ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` (this variable isn't set in the vcvars64.bat call chain). This overrides the location found in the `PATH`.

`set ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH=C:\Users\leo\llvm-symbolizer.exe` would set a custom symbolizer: note that the name *needs* to be `llvm-symbolizer.exe` !

`ASAN_SYMBOLIZER_PATH` can also point to a directory name instead of the executable (the runtime tries to find then `llvm-symbolizer.exe` in this directory) .

And: still the `PATH` to `msdia140.dll` is needed to ensure proper symbolizing.

Comment: Hi Leo. Feel free to accept your own answer if you solved the problem on your own.

Comment: Thank you Morten, however I wait a bit that perhaps someone can earn a reputation *which* environment variable the clang libs look at .

Comment: Thanks a lot this is exactly the problem I'm running into.